# How do you properly flush a cached XIB in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, image, caching, xcode6, assets

I have a simple XIB for a collection view cell and it has a `UIImageView` in it. I changed the name of the image asset that the image view referenced from `my-old-image-asset-name` to `new-image`, updated the image assets, then changed the name of the image that the image view referenced. Interface Builder looks the way I want it to, however when I run this in any of the simulators I get a warning saying:

*Could not load the "my-old-image-asset-name" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "my app's bundle identifier"*

This usually means that there's a cached XIB somewhere because the old image asset name no longer exists and because Interface Builder looks correct.

I have tried all of the following in various combinations with no success. The simulators still reference this old asset name, presumably from a cached XIB.

1. Searched my app for all references to `my-old-image-asset-name` and found none.
2. Deleting all Derived Data
3. Closing Xcode then deleting all Derived Data
4. Cleaning the project.
5. Deleting the contents of /var/folders
6. Deleting the app from the Simulator
7. "Reset Content and Settings" on each Simulator that exhibits this behavior.
8. Searching the web for various ways to clear the Xcode's cache. (which result in the basic steps above).
9. Searched S.O. but none of the results seem to address Xcode 6, yet.

I'm going bonkers here trying to get this stinkin' XIB to update but I'm stuck now. Any ideas?

Comment: There must be something wrong with Xcode 6's caching. The problem went away after cleaning the project.

Comment: Did this happen on a Simulator or also a device?

Comment: @race_carr This was from a while ago, but as I recall this was just a problem with the simulator.